# UIImage from AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, uiimage, avcapturesession

What I'm trying to achieve is grabbing a still frame from a AVCaptureSession for something like a QR Code scanner. I have a view with a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer sublayer.

I already tried using AVCaptureStillImageOutput, which worked, but that function makes the shutter sound. Since there's no way to mute that I can't use it. After that I tried to make a screenshot of the entire screen, which also failed, because it can't capture a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. Now I'm kinda lost, the only real way to do this would be to feed a video feed into my OCR library but that would lag to much/be a lot of work.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tech note describing exactly what you want to achieve:

[How to capture video frames from the camera as images using AV Foundation on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1702/_index.html)

Comment: Nice! Only thing I had to change was use     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.imageViewCrop setImage:image];
    });

Comment: How many times per second do you call `setImage:` because `CoeGraphics` isn't really built for high-performance drawing (say > 30 Hz).